# Expert system for android platform

Tags: android, expert-system

I would like to know what is the best solution to develop an expert system with a pretty large KB for android, should I simply use hundreds of if-else (suppose the user should choose just between YES and NO) or is there any engine that its generated KB can be used on in android.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Clarify your question and make it more specific - what has XML and if-else to do with each other? http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: I think he's talking about a state-machine for something like Asking a computer to  diagnose an illness based on symptoms *vague memory from university*

Comment: Jess (which is Java-based) can't be used, because it needs Java Beans that are not available on Android. I have not checked Drools yet (which is also Java-based).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [expertise2go](http://www.expertise2go.com/)'s [e2gDroid Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.expertise2go.e2gdroidlite&hl=en) which is an Android port of the e2gRuleEngine Java applet: a rule-based expert system "shell" used in Decision Support and Expert System courses around the world for more than 10 years. e2gDroid delivers mobile, interactive decision making tools in the form of rule-based expert systems on Android devices that implement at least the version 2.2 "Froyo" OS.

You can also develop Java Applets which you can embed in any web site using [expertise2go](http://www.expertise2go.com/).

You can download it from GooglePlay for Free and the tutorial is available at the company's site.

Answer (score 0):

Can you write a native C/C++ code for Android? If yes, so I can suggest you to look for CLIPS. There is a free .dll available http://clipsinterface.sourceforge.net/ .You can make a some sort of ontology if you need with `Protege 3` and then export it into CLIPS. The only bad think is that this stuff in ten years old and very outdated (at least the site is outdated and there are a lot of broken links). So.. If you want to experiment - go ahead, if not - I can't give you any assurance for this method. Good luck!